# How to calculate the sum of time with SQL SERVER?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to calculate the sum of following time fields with a sql query:

02:35
11:15
00:15

Result should be 14:05
How to do this with sql query?

Comment: You can't. `time` is a time-of-day, not a duration. You can't add two `9:00 AM` and get `6:00 PM`

Comment: The duplicate answer works by calculating the difference between the time field and midnight in eg minutes or seconds. `SUM(DATEDIFF(MINUTE, '0:00:00', WrkHrs))`

Comment: And then, I think in theory you could add it to the minimum time. But that gets 14:20.